# How to load page after checkbox 2 in 3 wait 10s (Using JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

```
    <div class="list">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="data1" name="data[]">
                <p>Training Room 1</p>

            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="data2" name="data[]">
                <p>Training Room 2</p>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="3" id="data3" name="data[]">
                <p>Training Room 3</p>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

> How to  load page after checkbox 2 in 3 wait 10s (Using JavaScript)

I want the page to load after 2 out of 3 checkboxes and wait 10 sec.

Comment: Do you want to show 2 checkbox and wait 10 seconds to show the third one?

Comment: Yes i want that

Comment: See my posted answer

Comment: Yes, I see but why I choose 1, it's alert.,

Comment: I want to choose 2 then alert

Comment: Please update your question to provide more information about what you want to do

Comment: I want to press checkbox 2 out of 3 and then load the page. (
Sorry I'm not good at English)